# Joomla empty user rows

Tags: php, sql, database, joomla

I have a issue with Joomla, I have multiple joomla instalations, and a short time ago I saw something strange. I have thousands and thousands of empty users regristerd on some of my sites.

The 3 sites that I know of. And the most of them are on different hosting providers.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3yUUG.png (all the 60 pages are filled with empty users)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/MqZkd.png (the database)

I searched on the internet, and I could't find a fix or a simular person that had this problem.

Maybe you guys now this problem?
Thank you very much :)

**EDIT:** I just had this problem with a new site on a testdomain (a domein that was newly generated and litterly was 30 min. old.) I don't think this is by bots.

And i checked for scripts in the system using RSFirewall.

Comment: Most probably coming from bots. The kind of bots that post spam comments on blog posts. I don't know how they could have registered with empty usernames but my guess would be, they're using a security flaw on Joomla!.

Comment: User regristration is turned off, and if you see the second link (the picture from the database) it are empty rows. So it's almost impossble that bots can do that.

Comment: They can most probably do that, they just need a way to bypass Joomla!'s mandatory fields checking (with a zero-day for example), either that or they could access your DB directly, which is far less likely to be the case.

Comment: I didn't now that they did that, and nobody on the internet has the same issues. (Then it would be specific bots for only my sites) :/

Answer (score 0):

It's Bot. check your site by findbot(http://www.abuseat.org/findbot.pl)

Comment: Checked it, and i have also RSFirewall installed on the website, but he could't find bots/scripts :/

Comment: RSFirewall could not find Bots.you can user findbot or search in files and detect bots.for example many bots(trojans,virus,...) use eval function.

Comment: The empty user regristrations are stopped :) I still dont know what the problem was. But thank you for your anwsers.